# M Query Table.Group with Min based on two columns

Tags: excel, grouping, powerquery

I have a table with many columns. Three of these columns are:

- Package Name (text)
- Units Required (Int.64)
- Assessment (Int.64)

What I am trying to do is to find the 'Minimum' "Package Name" first by selecting the smallest number of "Units Required", then because sometimes there are several instances where the number of required units will be the same, the row with the lowest "Assessment".

I am exploring the Table.Group() approach but I am not getting anywhere with my understanding of it. I am doing this in Power Query in Excel 365.

Psuedo Code would be something like:

- Table.Group("Previous Step Name",{"Package Name"},{MIN("Units Required"),MIN("Assessment")})

As an aside - is it possible to use a single Table.Group and group at two levels? such as "Package Name" and "Column X" so that the result would be a: for each "Package Name" then for each "Column X" in each "Package Name" (nested as it were).

Thankyou in advance for taking a look at this.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Cheers

The Frog

Comment: Please add some sample data with the result of what you're trying to achieve

Comment: Same. Sample data with desired results are needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qualia, thankyou for pointing me in the right direction.

The way that I solved this was really simple in the end!
Step 1: Sort the rows based on the grouping criteria (package name, system class) in that order

Step 2: Add an Index Column so each row has a unique ID to work with

Step 3: Group the table based on the same fields (package name, system class) and 'aggregate' on the lowest Index Number (MIN)

Step 4: Perform a 'Merge Queries' with a Left Outer Join using the Index Number as the matching field between your current 'step' and the step from earlier in the processing where the Index was added - you can then have the rows matched and only the rows needed will be matched since the others are now gone due to the MIN aggregation from earlier. Here is my example:

```
Table.NestedJoin(#"Grouped Rows", {"Winner"}, #"Added Index", {"Index"}, "Lookup Data", JoinKind.LeftOuter)

- Grouped Rows was the grouping step (Step 3)
- Winner is the name of the Index that had the minimum value
- Added Index was the last step before grouping that still had all the columns (Step 2)
- Index is the column that was added after the sort to uniquely number each row
```

Step 5: Expand the table and select the columns of data that you want to hang onto

Treating it a bit like a database was a good approach and I appreciate the suggestion you put together for me. Hopefully this will allow others to solve some of their problems too.

Cheers and many thanks

The Frog

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to do it step by step.

## Data

[image]

## Queries

### Load_Data

Load data from Excel table

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content]
in
    Source
```

### Min_Unit

Identify min unit by grouping with empty "group by" field.

```
let
    Source = Load_Data,
    Group = Table.Group(Source, {}, {{"Min_Unit", each List.Min([Units Required]), type number}})
in
    Group
```

### Min_Unit_And_Assessment

Use inner join to filter original data for entries which equal min_unit. Next, group by "units required" to get the min_assessment.

```
let
    Source = Table.NestedJoin(Load_Data, {"Units Required"}, Min_Unit, {"Min_Unit"}, "Min_Unit", JoinKind.Inner),
    Group = Table.Group(Source , {"Units Required"}, {{"Min_Assessment", each List.Min([Assessment]), type nullable number}})
in
    Group
```

### Result

Inner join to filter original data for the combination of min_unit and min_assessment.

```
let
    Source = Table.NestedJoin(Load_Data, {"Units Required", "Assessment"}, Min_Unit_And_Assessment, {"Units Required", "Min_Assessment"}, "Min_Unit_And_Assessment", JoinKind.Inner),
    RemoveUnnecessaryColumns = Table.RemoveColumns(Source,{"Min_Unit_And_Assessment"})
in
    RemoveUnnecessaryColumns
```

## Result

[image]

Comment: Ahhh! I see where you are heading with this. Almost treating like a database with some self joins. I will give this a crack and let you know. Thankyou for this innovative suggestion.